# Aggregate sum for set bits in NEON SIMD

Tags: simd, neon

I have an algorithm that operates on a large array of bytes. As a preprocessing step, I need to create for a given index a count of which bit is how often set in the array up to this point.

I can do this in C using the following (pseudo) code:

```
input: uint8_t values[COUNT];
output: uint32_t bitsum[COUNT+1][8];
       (bitsum[i][x] is the counter for the x-th bit being set in
        the PRECEEDING i bytes -- this makes bitsum[0][x] == 0)

// we skip first row
for (int i=1; i < COUNT+1; i++) {
   for (int bit=0; bit < 8; bit++) {
      bitsum[i][bit] = bitsum[i-1][bit];
      if (values[i-1] & (1 << bit) != 0) {
         bitsum[i][bit]++;
      }
   }
}
```

However I am hopign that I can achieve this faster using NEON SIMD. Unfortunately I am quite new to this so I have not been able to solve this (yet?) and looking for some help. Is it even possible to do this in NEON?

**UPDATE:**

Trying to speed this code up in C, I believe the following approach is the fastest (sans unrolling the inner for loop, of course):

```
// pre-calculate lookup-table
uint16_t lookup[256][8];
for (int value=0; value < 256; value++) {
   for (int bit=0; bit < 8; bit++) {
      if (value & (1 << bit) != 0) {
         lookup[value][bit]++;
      }
   }
}

// create sum
for (int i=1; i < COUNT+1; i++) {
   for (int bit=0; bit < 8; bit++) {
      bitsum[i][bit] = bitsum[i-1][bit] + lookup[values[i-1]][bit];
   }
}
```

This looks like it would be ideal for SIMD, except for the lookup-table access - at least I can not find a way to do that in NEON.

Comment: Should it be cumulative? Your description sounds to me as though it should, but then the example code doesn't do it.

Comment: @harold: thanks for spotting this, it indeed is supposed to be cumulative. I've fixed the pseudo code (it's obviously not optimized code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do table lookups in NEON using the `VTBL` and `VTBX` instructions, but they are only useful for look up tables with few entries. When optimising for NEON it is often best to look for a way to calculate values at run time instead of using a table.

In this example it is straightforward to calculate the lookup at run time. The function is essentially

```
int lookup(int val, int bit) { return (val & (1<<bit) >> bit); }
```

which can be converted to NEON SIMD easily.

So, your function can be implemented with NEON intrinsics like this:

```
#include <arm_neon.h>

void f(uint32_t *output, const uint8_t *input, int length)
{   

    static const uint8_t mask_vals[] = {  0x1,  0x2,  0x4,  0x8,
                                         0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80 };
    /* NEON shifts are left shifts, and we want a right shift,
       so use negative numbers here */
    static const int8_t shift_vals[] = { 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7 };

    /* constants we need in the main loop */
    uint8x8_t mask    = vld1_u8(mask_vals);
    int8x8_t shift    = vld1_s8(shift_vals);

    /* accumulators for results, bits 0-3 in cumul1, bits 4-7 in cumul2 */
    uint32x4_t cumul1 = vdupq_n_u32(0);
    uint32x4_t cumul2 = vdupq_n_u32(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {   
        uint8x8_t v = vld1_dup_u8(input+i);
        /* this gives 0 or 1 in each lane, depending on whether the
           appropriate bit is set */
        uint8x8_t incr = vshl_u8(vand_u8(v, mask), shift);

        /* widen to 16 bits */
        uint16x8_t incr_w = vmovl_u8(incr);

        /* increment the accumulators */
        cumul1 = vaddw_u16(cumul1, vget_low_u16(incr_w));
        cumul2 = vaddw_u16(cumul2, vget_high_u16(incr_w));
        /* store the accumulator values */
        vst1q_u32(output + i*8, cumul1);
        vst1q_u32(output + i*8 + 4, cumul2);
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: This code compiles, but I haven't tested it.